# What is the causing the discrepancies in rounding error between different machines?

Tags: go, operating-system, rounding-error

Consider the following code

```
func main() {
    var (
        negativeTwoThirds = -2.0 / 3.0
        negativeSix       = -6.0
        negativeThree     = -3.0
    )

    for _, v := range []float64{negativeTwoThirds} {
        four := negativeSix * v // 4 = (-6.0) * (-2/3)

        print1(negativeThree + four)
        print2(negativeThree, four)
    }
}

func print1(c float64) {
    fmt.Printf("%f (%b)\n", c, math.Float64bits(c))
}

func print2(a, b float64) {
    c := a + b
    fmt.Printf("%f (%b)\n", c, math.Float64bits(c))
}
```

I tried the code on a personal linux machine as well as on go playground ([demo](https://go.dev/play/p/YbSSB0uIhxE)) and it produced both times the output I was expecting

```
1.000000 (11111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
1.000000 (11111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
```

I tried the code on two macos machines and I got, both times, a rounding error

```
1.000000 (11111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110)
1.000000 (11111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
```

Can you help me make sense of the discrepancies

- between `print1` and `print2`?
- between different OS / architecture / go executables?

---

Note

- I can only trigger the discrepancy in a for loop
- I've used go version `1.20.x`
- Both macbook used for test use the Apple M1 chip (ARM instruction set) and the linux machine has a 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 (x86 instruction set)

---

EDIT: I reported the issue at https://github.com/golang/go/issues/61061

Comment: Some expressions are constants and some are float64, the difference isn’t surprising but the variation between OS might be. Is it the same architecture for both?

Comment: @JimB Huh, I find it surprising in the opposite way. That an ARM mac might have different fp semantics than a x86 Linux machine might well be the case, for example. But why do constant expressions get evaluated with (seemingly) less precision than floats at runtime?

Comment: @isaactfa Constants are evaluated with an unspecified arbitrary precision, much greater than that of a float64, but that difference can affect rounding when converting to floats. I wouldn’t expect the arch to affect the constant handling with the same compiler, but I’m looking for any confounding variables that might help explain things

Comment: >  Is it the same architecture for both?

Both macbook used for test use the Apple M1 chip, which use ARM-based instruction set. And the linux machine has a 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7  (x86) (info added into post) Thanks

Comment: JFTR, here at $dayjob we've recently obsevred difference in behavior between amd64 and arm64 (M1) when performing a type conversion `uint64(negativeFloat64)`. It's actually documented in the spec as such, but still a point of interest.

Comment: a simplified example with no constant handling: (https://go.dev/play/p/mQgjQmMmZmF) still shows something different in each line for darwin_arm64, and I don't see any order of operation differences either. Perhaps this is related to what @kostix mentioned, and is only showing up due to conversion in formatting, but this is starting to look more like a bug somewhere because I'm only able to trigger this within the for loop so far

Comment: If you will file an issue, please post the link to it here–I, for one, would like to follow it.

Comment: I reported the issue; https://github.com/golang/go/issues/61061. Let me know if you think I should close the post here.

Comment: I, for one, think your question is fine and legitimate. I'd keep it open; maybe you'll be able to answer it yourself when the cause of your issue will have been known (I hope!), this is fine as per the SO policies.

Comment: Ah, it's an optimization that is not hit within the loop! I don't know why I didn't try using `-gfclags -N`, but that causes the output to be the same in both cases on arm64 darwin.

Comment: @JimB, have you read the linked issue? ;-) It hints that the spec provides a kludge (if a bit non-obvious) to defeat the fusing when needed: on can explicitly type-convert the result to `float64` to the same effect.

Comment: @Remi.b, I think you could may be succintly summarise what bcmills and Ian Lance Taylor wrote, and accept your own answer–it's perfectly OK as per SO policy.

Comment: @kostix oh yes, I just meant that while checking over order-of-operations and constant evaluation I totally forgot to disable optimizations which was the confounding variable ;)